# Grouped, Bundled or other?

Tags: magento2, price, bundled-product, grouped-products

I am trying to create an offer for some tshirts. So basically I want to sell 5 tshirts for a certain price. The trouble i'm having is that when the items are added to the basket the amount is adding up to the price I want to sell the 5 tshirts for X5, so basically if i want to sell 5 tshirts for £15 its charging £75 as it's adding them all altogether. I've tried the Group and Bundle options, I've made sure the simple products (sizes and colours) are set to £0.00 but no luck, is it possible to do this without a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Set a tier price for the simple product of $3 for five or more, or create a promotional price rule to apply a similar discount.

Another alternative: create a simple product for your "five shirts" bundle at the desired price.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a separate product page for the bundle, use a **bundled product**, but when creating it, choose "Price type = Fixed". Then you can specify one price for the bundle, independent of the options.

Associate the simple products for the T-Shirts and set the selection qty to "User defined = no". You can still associate different variations of the T-Shirts so that the user can choose like this:

```
5x [ Red T-Shirt S     v]       (dropdown)
     Red T-Shirt M
     Red T-Shirt L
     Blue T-Shirt S
     Blue T-Shirt M
     Blue T-Shirt L
```